# Получить значение ячейки QTableWidget с делегатом ComboBox

Tags: qt, c++

Есть таблица, в которой для столбца применен делегат ComboBox. Как можно получить текущее текстовое значение ячейки из этого столбца?

Если делаю так:

```
QComboBox *combo = static_cast<QComboBox*>(ui->tableWidgetData->cellWidget(i,3));
combo->itemText(combo->currentIndex());
```

то прога вылетает с ошибкой сегментации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, нет? Если нет, выложи код, попробую помочь. Ошибка наверняка из-за того что combo null.

Comment: Разобрался, но я реализовал это не с помощью делегата, а с помощью

    ui->tableWidgetData->setCellWidget(n-1,3,new QComboBox(combo));

Написав коннект, который отлавливал изменение количества строк и добавлял или убирал этот комбо бокс с ячейки.

Код делегата у меня, к сожалению, не сохранился, но делегат я свистнул в тот раз отсюда http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_9566_0.html

Был еще один делегат, но я уже не помню, откуда я его брал.
Кстати, такая жа проблема с делегатом double. Вот его код:

Comment: Вот его код:

    class cDoubleDelegate : public QItemDelegate
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        cDoubleDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
        QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const; 
    };

Comment: cDoubleDelegate::cDoubleDelegate(QObject *parent) :
        QItemDelegate(parent)
    {
    }

    QWidget *cDoubleDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
        const QStyleOptionViewItem&,
        const QModelIndex&) const
    {
        QLineEdit *editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
        editor->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(editor));
        editor->setEnabled(true);
        return editor;
    }